# Bash script to delete line in CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a CSV file with million records for different users, there are multiple records for each user. I am doing some processing on the file and managed to get the record for each user which I want to delete.

I am using the below commands, but I can't delete the line I want to

```
get_date=$(grep -n "xyz@abc.com"  francis_test.csv| awk -F, '{print $22}' | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{print $1" "$2}'  |  sort -k 1.7n -k 1.4,1.5n -k 1.1,1.2n | tail -n1)

record=$(grep -n "xyz@abc.com"  francis_test.csv| grep "$get_date")
```

To delete the record I use the below command

```
sed '/"$record"/d'
```

Comment: I feel like with that many records, a proper database (Sqlite3 would be the simplest to use) might be better than CSV for pretty much anything you want to do with it.

Comment: millions of records you say? you might want to switch to at the very lest SQLlite.
However you are using 3 tools here where you can use one. all you need is awk or sed. I think things are getting list in the piping. However you are using sed wrong here. you want `sed -i "///"` formate not sed with the d operator

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to be able to help please provide your efforts as
shown in [Minimal, Reproducible
Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Single quote prevents the variable `record` from being expanded. Quote it like:

```
sed '/'"$record"/'d'
```

`sed` also has an option `-i` to in-place modification (if you want to actually delete the lines from the file).

```
sed -i.bak '/'"$record"/'d'
```

Providing a suffix to `-i` makes a backup of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

thanks but now i am facing issue with the the below command

get_date=$(grep -n "xyz@abc.com"  francis_test.csv| awk -F, '{print $22}' | sed 's/"//g' | awk '{print $1" "$2}'  |  sort -k 1.7n -k 1.4,1.5n -k 1.1,1.2n | tail -n1)

cant get the output all of a sudden it fails